# How use a "groupby + Sum" dataframe in a Dash pie diagram

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a data frame with a lot of info.
In the data frame i did a couple of filters at the end i made a new data frame with a groupby and a Sum like this:

```
df_new = df4.groupby(['date', 'app'])['usage'].apply(lambda x : x.astype(float).sum())
```

This code works as expected and gives me the following (simplified) output:

```
date        app

2019-05-26  app03                                                2.0
            app02                                                60.0
            app01                                                14.0

2019-05-27  app02                                                6.0
            app01                                                2.0

2019-05-28  app05                                                12.0
            app04                                                702.0
            app01                                                15.0
```

Now i like to make a Pie chart in the Dash app with this info, but because its a groupby i can’t use something like

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=df_new['app'], values=df_new['usage'], hole=.3)])
```

This because it’s one table? and can’t ask columns like "df_new['app']"
Is there a way to make a pie diagram from a groupd by data frame?
The next step is to make it Date specific

Comment: Can try explicitly convert columns to list or doing df_new=df_new.reset_index() but it's just a guess. Also notice how the new column in your new_df has no name, cant do df_new['usage']

Comment: I believe you can do `df_new = df4.groupby(['date', 'app']).apply({'usage' : lambda x : x.astype(float).sum()})` to retain column name

Comment: Tnx, IcedLance it worked, The pie chart is showing all of the data, do you maybe know how to add a slider so it is displayed per day?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar enough with Dash but you can get a list of all possible dates as `dates = list(set(df.date)), dates = dates.sort()` and then pick relevant subsets of data as `selection = df.loc[df.date==dates[0]]` if this helps.